# Android: Enabling bluetooth on call receive

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to enable bluetooth upon receiving a call. I have made the code to detect the incoming call by using `callstatelistener`. However, I am not able to trigger bluetooth activation from the same listener. I tried the following code but it gives me a compilation error as `The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type CallHelper.CallStateListener`. Could any of you please help me out?

```
final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
/**
 * Listener to detect incoming calls. 
 */

private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
    public boolean wasRinging;
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            // called when someone is ringing to this phone


            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 0);
            }
```

Comment: will somebody please care to reply?

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge is that your class needs to extends Activity class in order to be able to call the startActivityForResult() method. Hope this will help.